# How do I reorganize my pockets?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My inventory is full of clutter, and I can't seem to figure out a way to re-organize my inventory. How do I re-organize my inventory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you hold the <kbd>A</kbd> button down, you have the option to select an item and drag it to a location in your inventory you want, then releasing the A button places it in that position. Placing the item in the place of another item swaps the two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just hold A, move the item, and release it to move/swap it. I haven't had to do multiple taps